# PHP, cookie not being recognised as "set" when it is set

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have a cookie that identifies whether or not it is the user's first time opening a page. I have it so that when it is the first time, a cookie is set if its not already set. Everytime a user loads the page on a second or third attempt, the code checks for whether the cookie is set and does something..

However, for some reason on the second page load, the code does not find the cookie even though it is created in my chrome browser

```
<?php 

 $canvas_id = $_GET["canvas_id"];

 if (!isset($_COOKIE[$canvas_id]))
  {
    setcookie($canvas_id, "NO", time()+3600, '/'); 

  } 

  else
  {
    //do something...
  } ?>



  <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
  <html>
  <body>

  <?php

   if (isset($_COOKIE[$canvas_id]))
   {     
      echo ("HELLO");
    }

   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have it so that the cookie being created is passed from a previous page. I have tried changing the cookie value to a hard-coded variable and it works. Example:

```
    <?php 



 if (!isset($_COOKIE["test"]))
  {
    setcookie("test", "NO", time()+3600, '/'); 

  } 

  else
  {
    //do something...
  } ?>



  <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
  <html>
  <body>

  <?php

   if (isset($_COOKIE["test"]))
   {     
      echo ("HELLO");
    }

   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please explain why the first example code doesnt work but the second does?

Thanks alot

Comment: Are you sure that the variable that is retrieved via GET is the same each time for that user? i.e. what is the url when the user goes to the page the first, second and third times?

Comment: The variable from via GET may be different each time. I want to make it so that a new cookie is created if that cookie is not present, if the cookie with the variable name already exists, do something...

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Hope you will understand now whats going on in your first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this part of your code carefully `if (!isset($_COOKIE[$canvas_id]))`.
You are providing a variable as key of `$_COOKIE` global array. If you do not set the value of `$_GET["canvas_id"]` then the value of variable `$canvas_id` will be empty and `!isset()` will always return `true` and execute the`setcookie($canvas_id, "NO", time()+3600, '/');` part.

The `if (isset($_COOKIE[$canvas_id])){echo ("HELLO");}` part will never be executed since `$_COOKIE[$canvas_id]` is not set.

So if you want to execute your code correctly you have to run the code without value of `$_GET['canvas_id']` and then with value of `$_GET['canvas_id']` .

Like this:

Without `$_GET['canvar_id']` value link will be: 
http://localhost/cookie.php

With `$_GET['canvar_id']` value link will be: http://localhost/cookie.php?canvar_id=1234

(cookie.php is your code file).

Comment: What did u mean by send the variable value using GET request first? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Hope you will understand now whats going on in your first snippet.